# What is the difference between STABLE and MASTER in Git?

Tags: git, svn

Most of the documentation that I found says that both are the same, so I do not understand why they are there. Is there an equivalent to SVN?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as "stable" in git. You could create a branch with that name, but what that means is entirely up to you. It's common (but I don't know if it's required) that in git you have a branch named _master_.

Comment: The difference is that "stable" contains a 'b' and an 'l', while "master" contains an 'm' and an 'r', and they're all in different orders. `git` doesn't assign any significance to branch/tag names. It uses the name 'master' by default, but that's just a built-in default name with no additional significance, and is not required to exist or keep its name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're talking about branch names. When you initialize a new Git repository it automatically creates a branch named `master` for you.

There are people who also like to make a branch named `stable`. As the name indicates, it is usually a branch where the code is in a stable state. The `master` branch is then allowed to be unstable, so that developers can push their code to it without affecting the `stable` branch.

There are however also a lot of projects that treat the `master` branch as the stable one. They might have a `dev` branch where the feature branches first get merged into, so they can be tested before they'll be merged into `master`.

Everybody has a different workflow in Git, and there are some conventions, but you're not obligated to use them.